# Get count of values across columns-Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame like following:

```
               A              B              C
0   192.168.2.85   192.168.2.85  124.43.113.22
1  192.248.8.183  192.248.8.183   192.168.2.85
2  192.168.2.161            NaN  192.248.8.183
3   66.249.74.52            NaN  192.168.2.161
4            NaN            NaN   66.249.74.52
```

I want to get the count of a certain values across columns. So my expected output is something like:

```
IP          Count
192.168.2.85 3 #Since this value is there in all coulmns
192.248.8.183 3
192.168.2.161 2
66.249.74.52 2
124.43.113.22 1
```

I know how to this across rows, but doing this for columns is bit strange?Help me to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: @OP, would you consider accepting a more performant answer if it was given?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[stack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) it first and then use [value_counts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
In [14]: df.stack().value_counts()
Out[14]: 
192.248.8.183    3   
192.168.2.85     3   
66.249.74.52     2   
192.168.2.161    2   
124.43.113.22    1   
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Only pandas Series can use value_counts().  By using df.stack(), you transformed his DataFrame into a Series.  Your solution is correct, but knowing why it worked helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['Counts'] = df[['col1','col2','col3']].groupby(['col1','col2','col3']).transform('count')
```