# Count items in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` like following.

```
1   A  B  D     E  None
2   B  C  E  None  None
3   A  B  D     E  None
4   A  B  C     E  None
5   A  B  C     D     E
```

I want to count each item in the `DataFrame`. How to do it?

```
B(6), E(5), A(4), C(4), D(4) etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[stack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) it first and then use [value_counts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

data = \
"""A,B,D,E,None
B,C,E,None,None
A,B,D,E,None
A,B,C,E,None
A,B,C,D,E"""

# Creation of the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep = ',',header=None)
# Perform the magic operation (stack and value_counts) on the dataframe
res = df.stack().value_counts()
```

The result looks like:

```
E       5
B       5
None    5
A       4
C       3
D       3
dtype: int64
```

This question has already been [asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691447/get-count-of-values-across-columns-pandas-dataframe)