# Python: Pandas Create new csv with contents counted

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm reading in a csv and I'm trying to count how many times each entry appears
The csv looks like this:

```
     Image#     color1     color2    color3
     1          red        blue      yellow
     2          blue       blue      red
     3          white      red       pink
```

What I'm wanting to do is write it to a new csv with something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv("colors.csv")
counted = df.groupby(["color1", "color2", "color3"]).size()
df.to_csv("counted.csv")
```

except I want it to output

```
Red    3
Blue   3
Pink   1
Yellow 1
White  1
```

I'm fine if there isn't a way to do this, but how would I at least get the total occurrences of each of those colors? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Stack.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html

[Get count of values across columns-Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691447/get-count-of-values-across-columns-pandas-dataframe)

```
import pandas as pd

Dict = {'Image': [1,2,3],
    'color1': ['red','blue','white'],
    'color2': ['blue','blue','red'],
    'color3': ['yellow','red','pink']}

df = pd.DataFrame(Dict)
df.set_index('Image',inplace=True)

Color_Counts = df.stack().value_counts()
Color_Counts.to_csv('Color_Counts.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!