# How can I count the unique values from all columns and display them in a separate dataframe w.r.t. their unique name?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

```
| 1st Most Common Value | 2nd Most Common Value | 3rd Most Common Value | 4th Most Common Value | 5th Most Common Value |
|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| Grocery Store         | Pub                   | Coffee Shop           | Clothing Store        | Park                  |
| Pub                   | Grocery Store         | Clothing Store        | Park                  | Coffee Shop           |
| Hotel                 | Theatre               | Bookstore             | Plaza                 | Park                  |
| Supermarket           | Coffee Shop           | Pub                   | Park                  | Cafe                  |
| Pub                   | Supermarket           | Coffee Shop           | Cafe                  | Park                  |
```

The name of the dataframe is df0. As you can see there are many values repeating in all the columns. So I want to create a dataframe which has all the unique values with their frequencies from all the columns. Can someone please help with the code since I want to create a Bar plot of it?

The Output should be as follows:

```
| Venues         | Count |
|----------------|-------|
| Bookstore      | 1     |
| Cafe           | 2     |
| Coffee Shop    | 4     |
| Clothing Store | 2     |
| Grocery Store  | 2     |
| Hotel          | 1     |
| Park           | 5     |
| Plaza          | 1     |
| Pub            | 4     |
| Supermarket    | 2     |
| Theatre        | 1     |
```

Comment: What's your expected output? Also would be nice if you could paste the data not as an image

Comment: Start by running fd0.describe()

Comment: So basically you want `.value_counts()` for each column?

Comment: @NYCCoder I have modified my code, please do check and let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @GustavRasmussen I have modified my code, please do check and let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @CeliusStingher I have modified my code, please do check and let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I'll try to answer it in a bit!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get count of values across columns-Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691447/get-count-of-values-across-columns-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Tom Yes! It solved my problem. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: I got ahead of myself in my original answer (also thanks OP for adding the edit/expected output).  You want [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691447/get-count-of-values-across-columns-pandas-dataframe), I think the simplest answer:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df0.stack().value_counts())
```

---

If you don't care about which column the values are coming from, and you just want their counts, then use `value_counts()` (as @Celius Stingher said in the comments), following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691447/get-count-of-values-across-columns-pandas-dataframe).

If you do want to report the frequency of each value for each column, you can use `value_counts()` for each column, but you may end up with uneven entries (to get back into a `DataFrame`, you could do some sort of `join`).

I instead made a little function to count the occurrences of values in a `df`, and return a new one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def counted_entries(df, array):
    output = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns, index=array)
    for i in array:
        output.loc[i] = (df==i).sum()
    return output
```

This works for a `df` filled with random animal value names.  You just have to pass the unique entries in the `df` by getting the `set` of its values:

```
columns = ['Column ' + str(i+1) for i in range(10)]
index = ['Row ' + str(i+1) for i in range(5)]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['pig','cow','sheep','horse','dog'],size=(5,10)), columns=columns, index=index)

unique_vals = list(set(df.stack())) #this is all the possible entries in the df

df2 = counted_entries(df, unique_vals)
```

`df` before:

```
      Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4  ... Column 7 Column 8 Column 9 Column 10
Row 1      pig      pig      cow      cow  ...      cow      pig      dog       pig
Row 2    sheep      cow      pig    sheep  ...      dog      pig      pig       cow
Row 3      cow      cow      cow    sheep  ...    horse      dog    sheep     sheep
Row 4    sheep      cow    sheep      cow  ...      cow    horse      pig       pig
Row 5      dog      pig    sheep    sheep  ...    sheep    sheep    horse     horse
```

output of `counted_entries()`

```
       Column 1  Column 2  Column 3  ...  Column 8  Column 9  Column 10
pig           1         2         1  ...         2         2          2
horse         0         0         0  ...         1         1          1
sheep         2         0         2  ...         1         1          1
dog           1         0         0  ...         1         1          0
cow           1         3         2  ...         0         0          1
```

Comment: I think pandas has enough functions so as to not need to define a custom function, but great answer all the same! +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the edit, maybe this is what you are looking for, using `value_counts` for the full dataframe and then aggregating the output:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'1st':['Grocery','Pub','Hotel','Supermarket','Pub'],
                    '2nd':['Pub','Grocery','Theatre','Coffee','Supermarket'],
                    '3rd':['Coffee','Clothing','Supermarket','Pub','Coffee'],
                    '4th':['Clothing','Park','Plaza','Park','Cafe'],
                    '5th':['Park','Coffee','Park','Cafe','Park']})

df1 = df0.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
df1['Count'] = df1.sum(axis=1)
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Venues'}).drop(columns=list(df0))
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
        Venues  Count
5         Park    5.0
2       Coffee    4.0
7          Pub    4.0
8  Supermarket    3.0
0         Cafe    2.0
1     Clothing    2.0
3      Grocery    2.0
4        Hotel    1.0
6        Plaza    1.0
9      Theatre    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',')
list_of_list = df.values.tolist()
t_list = sum(list_of_list, [])
df = pd.DataFrame(t_list)
df.columns = ['Columns']
df = df.groupby(by=['Columns'], as_index=False).size().to_frame().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'Count'})
print(df)

           Columns  Count
0        Bookstore      1
1             Cafe      2
2   Clothing Store      2
3      Coffee Shop      4
4    Grocery Store      2
5            Hotel      1
6             Park      5
7            Plaza      1
8              Pub      4
9      Supermarket      2
10         Theatre      1
```